# Grouping timestamps per status per user SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, timestamp, grouping, sql-server-2014

I have googled and went through stackoverflow for 3 days now. And I have bit of a challenge. So here is the problem/challenge.

I have raw data such as this:

```
Employee Id    Pay Date    Time In           Time Out         Cost Center 3
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 10:13    7-8-2015 10:27    3103
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 10:27    7-8-2015 11:20    2004
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 11:20    7-8-2015 11:32    1001
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 11:32    7-8-2015 12:04    2004
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 12:04    7-8-2015 12:06    2004
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 12:06    7-8-2015 12:06    2004
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 12:06    7-8-2015 12:28    2004
   91458       7-8-2015    7-8-2015 14:01    7-8-2015 14:33    1002
```

but the output I need is this:

```
Employee Id   Pay Date    Time In          Time Out        Cost Center 3
   91458      7-8-2015    7-8-2015 10:13   7-8-2015 10:27      3103
   91458      7-8-2015    7-8-2015 10:27   7-8-2015 11:20      2004
   91458      7-8-2015    7-8-2015 11:20   7-8-2015 11:32      1001       
   91458      7-8-2015    7-8-2015 11:32   7-8-2015 12:28      2004
   91458      7-8-2015    7-8-2015 14:01   7-8-2015 14:33      1002
```

This is on SQL Server 2008 but the data will be migrated to a SQL Server 2014 machine in 40 days so a SQL Server 2014 solution is also helpful.

Regards,
Gary

Comment: would you mind to elaborate more on the difference between the two data set as well as what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes. in the top part you see cost center 3 with 2004 in it.  its about the 2nd group starting with time in 7-8-2015 11:32 you see 4 lines with the code 2004 and i need to group it up so i get 1 line with the time in of 7-8-2015 11:32 but the time out of the last cost center 2004 with a time out of 7-8-2015 12:28.   i have already tried working with ranking,dense ranking, emulating lag and lead. as wel as joining the data on it self. any help is appreciated.. 200X is a productive state 100X is a braek state and 310X is a DND state.